# GitHub Action to publish assets

Tags: github-actions

I have one GitHub Action that is transforming a design tokens json file into a CSS file containing variables. That is working ok.
I have another `yml` file that only starts up after the first workflow has finished:

```
name: Package

# Only trigger, when the transform workflow succeeded
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["transform"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  publish-gpr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

I just want to publish the CSS file as a package on GitHub Packages or NPM.

I am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the [publishConfig](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#publishconfig) to your `package.json` file:

```json
"publishConfig": {
  "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
}
```

Also, please make sure that your package is [scoped](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scope):

```json
"name": "@<gh-user-or-org>/<repo>"
```

Make sure that your `package-lock.json` is also updated (since the `npm ci` command relies on it). For more details, read the [Publishing a package](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#publishing-a-package).

To publish your package to the regular NPM registry you need to store your **npm authentication** token as a secret. For example, create a repository secret called `NPM_TOKEN`. For more information, see [Creating and using encrypted secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets).

To generate an npm token, you need to log in to your [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/) account, click your *Profile picture* > *Access Tokens* > *Generate New Token* > *Classic Token*. Make sure to choose the *Automation* token type.

After creating a repository secret with the npm token, make sure to update the workflow:

```
NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: I would rather publish to GitHub packages, rather than the NPM registry. I think that GITHUB_TOKEN should work for publishing as to Github Packages.

Comment: This line of code tells the action to publish to GitHub Packages `registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/`

Comment: @OllieWilliams just updated the answer. In my case, your workflow works for me after specifying the `publishConfig` and making the package scoped